# Upload Zip file using REST requests library in Robot Framework

Tags: python-requests, robotframework

Can anyone provide a working example of how to upload a zip file using the python request library in Robot Framework?

I have tried a lot of examples, but the best I can get is a status code of 415

```
// the zip file, I have tried both ways to get the data
${pathZipFile}    Set Variable    ${EXECDIR}\\Files\\File.zip
${fileData}    Get Binary File    ${pathZipFile}
${fileData}    Get File    path=${pathZipFile}    encoding=CP437
&{dictFiles}    Create Dictionary    CDMZipFile=${fileData}

// the request
&{headers}    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=multipart/form-data    Accept=application/json
Create Session    alias=${sessionId}    url=${url}    headers=${headers}
${resp}    Put Request    alias=${sessionId}    uri=${uri}    files=${dictFiles}    headers=${headers}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as yourself - to solve it I needed to create a multipart (created in python) request - normal post/put request did not work
----edit more info----
Search in your framework files where you have created the post/put method
And add a new method for a post/put multipart upload
Something like this( I just copied and edited the post one to include multiple files instead of a normal body)
response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)